# Show alert popup on standard page layout on click of standard button "Save"

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, page-layout

I need to implement alert popup on standard page layout on click of standard button "Save".How can i achieve it.I tried google but not getting a valid implementation.Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a Visualforce page, as you can't override the standard edit page buttons. Also, see [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) for something you can vote on.

Comment: Still idea has not been implemented as per comments of that post.Do i need to override save button with a VF page? Do you mean to say ?

Comment: @RobertBarnett Yes, your only means today is an override. But do remember to vote, too. I want this feature, too.